# How to SQL query actual Pricelist grouped by several columns

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have following table in postgres (product and variant are foreign key ids to another tables but I used product/variant names to make it more readable):

| id | productId | variantId | validFrom | currencyCode | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | iphone | X | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 19 |
| 2 | iphone | X | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 29 |
| 3 | iphone | X | 2021-03-01 | EUR | 39 |
| 4 | iphone | 12 | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 49 |
| 5 | macbook | air | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 59 |
| 6 | macbook | air | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 69 |
| 7 | macbook | pro | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 79 |
| 8 | macbook | pro | 2021-01-01 | USD | 89 |

Now when I need pricelist valid for a date **2021-01-20** the result should be:

| product | variant | validFrom | currencyCode | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | X | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 19 |
| iphone | 12 | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 49 |
| macbook | air | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 59 |
| macbook | pro | 2021-01-01 | USD | 89 |

but when I need pricelist valid for a date **2021-02-08** the result should be:

| product | variant | validFrom | currencyCode | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| iphone | X | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 29 |
| iphone | 12 | 2021-01-01 | EUR | 49 |
| macbook | air | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 69 |
| macbook | pro | 2021-02-01 | EUR | 79 |
| macbook | pro | 2021-01-01 | USD | 89 |

Any suggestion how to write the query?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one way :

```
select * from table t1
where id in ( 
  select id from table t2 
  where t1.productId = t2.productId 
  and t1.careintid = t2.varientid
  and t2.validfrom<= '<date param>'
  order by validfrom desc limit 1
)
```

or using window function:

```
select * from(
   select *, row_number() over (partition by productid, varientid order by case when validfrom <= '<dateparam>' then 1 else 0 end desc, validfrom desc) rn
) t where rn = 1
```

Comment: I have finally found the "one way" by myself but the "even better" is something I've not known... Definitely need to find some docs to understand it better... thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH cte AS
  (SELECT productid AS Product,
          variantid AS variant,
          validfrom,
          currencycode,
          price,
          Row_number() OVER(PARTITION BY productid, variantid
                            ORDER BY To_date(validfrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD') DESC) AS RNUM
   FROM tbl
   WHERE To_date(validfrom, 'YYYY-MM-DD') <= '2021-02-08')
SELECT product,
       variant,
       validfrom,
       currencycode,
       price
FROM cte
WHERE rnum = 1;
```

Here `tbl` is the tableName